# JavaFXObject Custom classes: how to retrive the text from javaFXObjects

Tags: java, javafx, vbscript, hp-uft, testcomplete

I wanted to retrieve the text from `JavaFXObjects`, Objects properties are below:

```
JavaClassName : =  TEValidationsController$4$1

JavaFullClassName := com.wf.App.client.feature.te.ValidationsController$4$1

JavaFXObjectName := message
```

I have tried number of methods like:

1. `objTable.wValue(Row,Col)`
2. `objTable.myObj.GetTex` , `objTable.myObj.Text`
3. `objTable.myObj.JavaFXObjectText`
    
   All return blank value.

Comment: Is this Java code? What is the meaning of the notation? What is `JavaFXObjects`? Please clarify your question and/or reference to any libraries you are using - it's very hard to understand your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get a custom control. Please contact the control developer or find its reference. You need to find out how to get the desired value programmatically from the tested application code itself. You should be able to use the same approach in a TestComplete script.